# Adding users to powerapps outside of the companies domain

Tags: powerapps

There are really 2 questions here:

1. Can Power Apps be logged into by someone who does not have an Office 365 account? It appears as though that is not the case.
2. Can users outside of the organization in which a Power App was made access and use it if permissions could be provided and assuming the user has the general ability to login to Power Apps?

Answer (score 0):

PowerApps can be shared with Guest users of the tenant. Guest users can be Users but not Co-owners of a PowerApp.

For more details please refer to this Microsoft Announcement from August 2019.

[Share canvas apps with guests in your organization](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/share-canvas-apps-with-guests-in-your-organization/)